# Android Date Format Help

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

Hi guys i am using a simple code to get current date and change its format but i am unable to do so every time i use the SimpleDateFormat class the application crashes with out being executed.

I am pasting my code here:

```
    Date d=new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY",Locale.ENGLISH);
  String newd= formatter.format(d);
```

can some body point out my mistake that i am making here??

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: please paste your stack trace of that crash to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

`YYYY` should be `yyyy`

- [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)